# Aigram системные сообщения

Tags: python, aiogram

перерыл весь интернет, но не могу найти ответа. Задача проста, нужно настроить бота чтобы он автоматически удалял системные сообщения о вступлении или удалении из группы. Если кто то сталкивался с такой задачей, буду благодарен за подсказку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение, в данных быблиотеках есть специальные методы для подобных сообщений.

Aiogram:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types = ['new_chat_members', 'left_chat_member'])
async def delete(message):
    await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Telebot и т.п.:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['new_chat_members', 'left_chat_member'])
def delete(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Comment: спасибо тебе добрый человек!

Comment: Можешь, пожалуйста, отметить как принятый ответ, чтобы закрыть вопрос =)